# How to prevent keyboard disappearing after input submission using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Currently, I have a chat application where the user is able to enter messages in the textarea. When a user writes in the textarea and sends the message, the keyboard disappears. If the user wants to send another message, he needs to click the input box again to write the message.

I want to prevent the keyboard from disappearing after sending a message.

Is this possible using jQuery?

Comment: How are you rendering the keyboard? You're talking about mobile or desktop? Can you show us some code?

Comment: In mobile , I needed... For textarea tag

Comment: You will need to add focus to the next textarea, so keyboard remains visible.

Comment: Try to focus that textarea using jQuery after the message sent.